# code for bulk CSV files in a directory to convert to xlsx

Tags: excel, powershell

I used below code to convert file from CSV to xlsx. But it only convert single file at a time. I want this to convert all the files in directory at a time.

```
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $true
$Workbook = $xl.Workbooks.Open("$loglocation\errors_$server.csv")
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.Worksheets

$Workbook.SaveAs("$loglocation\errors_$server.xls",1)
$Workbook.Saved = $true

$xl.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, should work:

```
 $filePath = Get-ChildItem -Path "path to csv"  -filter *.csv

 foreach ($file in $filePath )
 {
    $filename = $file.FullName
    $filename

    $xl = new-object -comobject excel.application
    $xl.visible = $true
    $Workbook = $xl.workbooks.open($filename)
    $Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets

    $Workbook.SaveAs($filename.Substring(0,$filename.Length-4) + ".xlsx",1)
    $Workbook.Saved = $True

    $xl.Quit()
 }
```

Can move the excel connections outside the loop as well if you need to speed it up

Comment: Move Excel instance creation and termination outside the loop. It's a waste of resources to do that over and over for each conversion.

Answer (score 1):

With the [PSExcel](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel) Module you can use `Export-XLSX` which makes this process very simple:

```
$loglocation = "C:\folder"

Get-ChildItem -Path $loglocation -Filter *.csv | foreach {
    Export-XLSX -InputObject $_ -Path "$loglocation\$($_.BaseName).xlsx"
}
```